# Android application is getting terminated when a automatic update takes place by Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, automatic-updates

I have a android application developed for HoneyComb and ICS version tablet that will be playing Images like a electronic photo frame, I have set the display to be always active using "keep screen on" to not let the device to go to sleep mode.

Would like to have the Google play auto update to work for the application. Hence was expecting that the Google Play would download the application in the background and once the current running application is manually closed and when re-opened will start with the updated version.

But practically when the application is set a side playing the images, and after prolonged 36 hours, I see that the application got automatically closed and when tried opening the application it was of the new version (i.e. the google play has updated the application automatically)

Does google play terminate an application which is in use when a new update is downloaded for the application?

Answer (score 0):

The app is not being killed when the new version is downloaded, but when the new version is being installed.